# Analyze methods count of an Android library

Tags: android, dex, android-multidex

I recently in my project get 65536 error message about dex size and blahblah.
and now I'm trying to reduce my dex size but I don't know exactly which of my libraries is adding more size to dex file. I just can see whole dex file size in apk analyzer. Is there a tool or way to analyze dex file and getting information about how many methods this library has and how much adding to my dex file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this gradle plugin

https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

It's the best to find the number of methods of your app in total or per library

Answer (score 1):

Also if you prefer to check the methods count in advance, you can check this tool:

<strike>www.methodscount.com</strike>

UPDATE: Not maintained anymore

Comment: it's not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add multidex support in your project settings. That should solve your problem.